# SVN SERVER SIDE REPOSITORY

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

How to change the url or repository from https://user-THINK/svn/sample/ became svn://ip address/name of repository

Comment: You should be able to supply the IP address of user-THINK instead of the name, so not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN Server does not support `svnserve`. HTTP(S) access is supported only. Technically, you can configure `svnserve` but it's not supported. You won't be able to use Active Directory authentication and authorization as well as other features of VisualSVN Server.

Moreover, there are practically no benefits from using `svnserve` if you already have VisualSVN Server installed.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Subversion [`svnserve` daemon.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html)